# Open a c++ project in Github with visual studio-Error

Tags: c++, opencv, github

https://github.com/DLuensch/StereoVision-ADCensus, Adcensus is error. Example cannot open source file "libconfig.h++"   Project1
cannot open source file "boost/filesystem.hpp"  Project1
cannot open source file "boost/date_time.hpp"   Project1

There are 39 error. Can you help me. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

StereoVision-ADCensus is based on following libraries, which ar not part of the git repository:
OpenCV
BOOST
**libConfig**
PCL
OpenMP
Qt 4.8.X